# Key Generation Using Ansible

Tags: ansible, ssh-keys, ssh-keygen

I have a question,whether it is possible to create SSH key without storing locally,instead of i can save it as  a variable.Whether is there any option so that i can have my keys safely without saving locally.

Thanks

Comment: If you just have it in a variable, but not stored, how will you use it?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Are you generating new keys on the fly, or just trying to store static keys?  Are you storing them on the destination machines?

Comment: Main scope is i need to avoid storing key locally instead of that i have been stored in any of my object storage using ansible

Comment: I was trying to solve this problem as I was generating keypairs and storing them in a database or any other cloud storage.

Comment: If it is not possible means without storing locally,whether we can  use crypto library in python for generating sshkeys with username specific,same as ssh???

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit hacky, but answers the question:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - expect:
        command: ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa -f /dev/stdout -q
        responses:
            Overwrite: y
            Enter: "\n"
      failed_when: "'BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY' not in priv_key_raw.stdout"
      changed_when: false
      register: priv_key_raw

    - set_fact:
        priv_key: "{{ (priv_key_raw.stdout_lines[3:])[:-1] }}"

    - shell: "/bin/echo -e \"{{ priv_key | join('\\n') }}\" | ssh-keygen -y -f /dev/stdin"
      register: pub_key_raw
      changed_when: false

    - set_fact:
        pub_key: "{{ pub_key_raw.stdout }}"

    - debug: var=priv_key
    - debug: var=pub_key
```

Comment: Hey thanks Suvorov.But whether we can use ec2_key module for pem file generation and extract a required key of public and private bu using any crypto libraries of python in Ansible instead of using ssh keygen by mentioning with the filepath like "/dev/".So that we can securely handle our key without storing temporarily.Is it possible?

Comment: @hain i'm sure there are a lot of hacky ways to do this, but if you really need this in production, you should write your own ansible module with some libs help, maybe (pycryptodome)[https://github.com/Legrandin/pycryptodome]

Comment: Thanks Suvorov once again.So if we using ec2_key module in ansible means it will give me only generated pem file which means it gives me a private key not public key ,am i right?

Comment: @hain Yes, only private key. But keep in mind, that `ec2_key` don't work locally – it connects to AWS EC2 cloud and generate key there.

Comment: Yeah right dude thanks,so  from that  we can generate publickey using any libraries,am i right Suvorov...which relates.